# Unreal Engine custom camera

Tags: camera, unreal-4, scripting

I was looking at game engines and found Unreal Engine. I want to make a game where the player has to create a camera by crafting it and can customize how many pixels the camera detects and what the camera detects (Ex: Sound, light, energy, etc). How could I do this?

Comment: This seems a bit like an [XY-Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What do you mean with "detect the environment" and "full control over the camera"? What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Do you mean something like have the camera collide with the environment? You can always make the camera a child of a collider object, but I suspect that would be a bad choice, as physics might cause the camera to move too fast to look good.

Comment: I rewrote the question in hopes to clarify it